# Where are the swift/swiftc binaries for v3?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3, xcode8

I've just downloaded the Xcode 8 beta, and am struggling to figure out where the `swift` and `swiftc` binaries are hidden.

The [Swift website](https://swift.org/getting-started/#installing-swift) says that the toolchain should be available at `/Library/Developer/Toolchains` and that it can be exported for use on command line with:

`$ export PATH=/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain/usr/bin:"${PATH}"`

But that path doesn't seem to exist for me.

I can see `Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain`, but that's for 2.3 rather than 3.

Any ideas?

Comment: `find / -name swift -type f` should find it

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!

Comment: You can also tell by looking at the build output window and inspecting a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b)'s suggestion:

```
⇒  find / -name swift -type f
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
/Users/myusername/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
/Users/myusername/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
/usr/bin/swift
```

Which for me are:

```
⇒  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift --version
Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

⇒  /Users/myusername/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift --version
Apple Swift version 2.3 (swiftlang-800.10.6 clang-800.0.24.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

⇒  /Users/myusername/Desktop/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift --version
Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.30 clang-800.0.24)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

⇒  /usr/bin/swift --version
Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

To set v3 as your 'main' swift, you can do the following (make sure to use the right path to your Xcode 8 application):

```
⇒  sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer

⇒  xcrun --find swift
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift

⇒  swift --version
Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.30 clang-800.0.24)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Arsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5328417/arsen) notes in [Run Swift 3 from command line using Xcode 8 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037971/run-swift-3-from-command-line-using-xcode-8-beta), you can also change the settings through the Xcode menu directly. Just follow **Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools**. Then switch the drop down list from Xcode 7.3.1 to Xcode 8.0. Then enter your password for admin privileges. However, for scripting, `xcode-select` is the most useful answer.

[image: Change Command Line Tools in Xcode Preferences]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzi3q.png